# application of morera's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

i am reading bak's complex analysis and it introduces an application of morera's theorem: proving a function is holomorphic. the author justifies the interchange of the order of integration( one is a complex line integral along a rectangle and the other is a real integral). does the justification of the interchange of integrals follows from fubini theorem? where should i refer to for the proof of the theorem? i am little confused because both complex, real integration is involved.[image] thank you.

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ uniformly then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_\gamma f_n(z)dz = 0$ whenever $\gamma$ is a finite length closed contour. This is enough for saying $F(z) = \int_a^z f(s)ds$ is well-defined and holomorphic

Comment: this is not about the sequence of funtions. only the part of the picture above the def 7.5 is relevant.

Comment: What I wrote is if $f_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions. If it is analytic, then proving the uniform limit $f(z)$ is analytic is almost trivial (write down the Taylor series). And what I mean is that you should forget about integrals and Fubini, look instead at the general case : sequences of holomorphic functions converging (locally) uniformly.

Comment: Well please read my question carefully. this is about the interchange of integrals(fubini thm), not the uniform convergence. i think you read the def 7.5 and thm 7.6 in the picture.

Comment: then how do you apply it for my problem? i don't know how to construct the sequence of functions because no sequence of functions is given in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Suppose $D:=\{z\in\mathbb{C} | \mathrm{Re}(z)<0\}$ and $\gamma:[0,a] \to D$ be a $C^1$-curve. Putting 
$c:=-\max_{0\leq\theta\leq a}\mathrm{Re}(\gamma(\theta))\quad(>0)$ and $B:=\max_{0\leq\theta\leq a}|\gamma'(\theta)|$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|\frac{e^{t\gamma(\theta)}}{t+1} \cdot \gamma'(\theta)\right| \leq Be^{-ct}
\end{eqnarray}
for all $t\geq 0$, $0 \leq \theta \leq a$.

Thus the function $\left|\frac{e^{t\gamma(\theta)}}{t+1} \cdot \gamma'(\theta)\right|$ is integrable on $t\geq 0$, $0\leq \theta \leq a$.

Therefore
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{tz}}{t+1} dt dz
= \int_0^a \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{t\gamma(\theta)}}{t+1} \cdot \gamma'(\theta) dt d\theta\\
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^a \frac{e^{t\gamma(\theta)}}{t+1} \cdot \gamma'(\theta) d\theta dt
= \int_0^\infty \int_\gamma \frac{e^{tz}}{t+1} dzdt
\end{align}
by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: thank you for the great answer.